is the word presumed used correctly in my sentence?
what was wrong with account I told her since Shes not on the acct I couldn't  provide her with details. I presumed to ask about the relationship, and she said she was the caregiver.

You might want to ask this over on our site for English Language Learners, https://ell.stackexchange.com/.

The passage you provide does not really qualify as technical writing. Its grammar, punctuation, and capitalization are flawed, and as a result, your meaning cannot be worked out.

@Ben:  Questions like this are off-topic at ELL.  This would get closed immediately.
